# BGP local-as command clarification

Tags: routing, bgp, arista

On my network infrastructure, an Arista switch is the core switch and a pfsense server the gateway. BGP is used to advertise routes for all the internal networks. On Arista switch, I see the BGP configured like that:

```
router bgp 65009
   vrf XXXXX
      local-as 65008
      router-id 172.X.X.1
      neighbor 172.X.X.2 remote-as 65007
      neighbor 172.X.X.2 maximum-routes 12000
      redistribute connected
```

My question is "Why may local-as have been configured without neighbor 172.X.X.1? Is there any functional difference if we don't add the neighbor command?" I would expect to see like that:

```
router bgp 65009
       vrf XXXXX
          neighbor 172.X.X.2 local-as 65008
          router-id 172.X.X.1
          neighbor 172.X.X.2 remote-as 65007
          neighbor 172.X.X.2 maximum-routes 12000
          redistribute connected
```

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you're asking here, can you please try to improve your question?

Comment: @TeunVink I added a section of what I would expect to see as a configuration regarding BGP. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options you have mentioned are valid.

Setting `local-as` per neighbor is just for that reason, keeping each neighbor explicitly configured, in case you had multiple neighbors with different local AS numbers.

```
neighbor 172.X.X.2 local-as 65008
```

Setting `local-as` without an explicit neighbor statement makes more sense when there is more than one neighbor.  If you had many neighbors, you only have to specify local-as once, rather than on every single neighbor.  This can make configuration a bit easier to maintain as the number of neighbors grow.  A potential example of this is in an EBGP underlay in a datacenter.

```
local-as 65008
neighbor 172.X.X.2 remote-as 65007
neighbor 172.X.X.2 remote-as 65009
neighbor 172.X.X.2 remote-as 65010
neighbor 172.X.X.2 remote-as 65011
neighbor 172.X.X.2 remote-as 65012
```